# node app crashing after upgrading fro v4.13.7 to 5.0.1

Tags: node.js, mongoose

my node application is working fine with mongoose version 4.13.7 but it crashing after upgrading to lastest mongoose version. It showing cycle dependency detected.

/Users/yogesh_bansal/workzone/Projects/apiserver/node_modules/mongoose/lib/utils.js:417
        throw err;
        ^

Error: cyclic dependency detected
    at serializeObject (/Users/yogesh_bansal/workzone/Projects/apiserver/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/parser/serializer.js:296:33)
    at serializeInto (/Users/yogesh_bansal/workzone/Projects/apiserver/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/parser/serializer.js:776:17)
    at serializeObject (/Users/yogesh_bansal/workzone/Projects/apiserver/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/parser/serializer.js:308:18)
    at serializeInto (/Users/yogesh_bansal/workzone/Projects/apiserver/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/parser/serializer.js:776:17)
    at serializeObject (/Users/yogesh_bansal/workzone/Projects/apiserver/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/parser/serializer.js:308:18)
    at serializeInto (/Users/yogesh_bansal/workzone/Projects/apiserver/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/parser/serializer.js:776:17)
    at serializeObject (/Users/yogesh_bansal/workzone/Projects/apiserver/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/parser/serializer.js:308:18)
    at serializeInto (/Users/yogesh_bansal/workzone/Projects/apiserver/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/parser/serializer.js:776:17)
    at serializeObject (/Users/yogesh_bansal/workzone/Projects/apiserver/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/parser/serializer.js:308:18)
    at serializeInto (/Users/yogesh_bansal/workzone/Projects/apiserver/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/parser/serializer.js:776:17)
    at serializeObject (/Users/yogesh_bansal/workzone/Projects/apiserver/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/parser/serializer.js:308:18)
    at serializeInto (/Users/yogesh_bansal/workzone/Projects/apiserver/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/parser/serializer.js:776:17)
    at serializeObject (/Users/yogesh_bansal/workzone/Projects/apiserver/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/parser/serializer.js:308:18)
    at serializeInto (/Users/yogesh_bansal/workzone/Projects/apiserver/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/parser/serializer.js:776:17)
    at serializeObject (/Users/yogesh_bansal/workzone/Projects/apiserver/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/parser/serializer.js:308:18)
    at serializeInto (/Users/yogesh_bansal/workzone/Projects/apiserver/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/parser/serializer.js:776:17)
    at serializeObject (/Users/yogesh_bansal/workzone/Projects/apiserver/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/parser/serializer.js:308:18)
    at serializeInto (/Users/yogesh_bansal/workzone/Projects/apiserver/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/parser/serializer.js:776:17)
    at serializeObject (/Users/yogesh_bansal/workzone/Projects/apiserver/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/parser/serializer.js:308:18)
    at serializeInto (/Users/yogesh_bansal/workzone/Projects/apiserver/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/parser/serializer.js:618:17)
    at serializeObject (/Users/yogesh_bansal/workzone/Projects/apiserver/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/parser/serializer.js:308:18)
    at serializeInto (/Users/yogesh_bansal/workzone/Projects/apiserver/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/parser/serializer.js:776:17)
    at BSON.serialize (/Users/yogesh_bansal/workzone/Projects/apiserver/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/bson.js:58:27)
    at Query.toBin (/Users/yogesh_bansal/workzone/Projects/apiserver/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/commands.js:141:25)
    at serializeCommands (/Users/yogesh_bansal/workzone/Projects/apiserver/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:1050:43)
    at Pool.write (/Users/yogesh_bansal/workzone/Projects/apiserver/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:1230:3)
    at executeWrite (/Users/yogesh_bansal/workzone/Projects/apiserver/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/wireprotocol/3_2_support.js:80:10)
    at WireProtocol.insert (/Users/yogesh_bansal/workzone/Projects/apiserver/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/wireprotocol/3_2_support.js:91:3)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem, solved this by setting autoIndex to false for now.
I suppose there is a compatibility problem with Indexes when using Mongo 3.6.3 and Mongoose 5

```
mongoose.connect(config.database, { autoIndex: false });
```